# Django FCGI Virtualenv 500 errors

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, mod-fcgid

I did get a blank Django project to work but it was version 1.3.1 which can't handle my 1.4.1 code. So I created a Virtualenv and installed the latest Django but can only get 500 errors.

Launching Django from mod_fcgid on Apache in a Virtualenv. I get these in the Apache log each time.

```
File "/home/user/django/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 58, in get_internal_wsgi_application
File "/home/user/django/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/fastcgi.py", line 183, in runfastcgi
File "/home/user/django/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 58, in get_internal_wsgi_application
File "/home/user/django/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/fastcgi.py", line 183, in runfastcgi
```

The line numbers correspond to these respectively

```
"could not import module '%s': %s" % (app_path, module_name, e))
WSGIServer(get_internal_wsgi_application(), **wsgi_opts).run()
```

and the first is inside the definition of `get_internal_wsgi_application()`.

What's causing this?

Is there a way to get more helpful debug info in the Apache log?

Why are the errors duplicating?

**UPDATE**

I'll be interested if anyone knows what's happening here, but since Web2py works fine under the same conditions I'm considering this an issue with Django and moving on.

Comment: Can you see a complete stack trace in apache's error_log? It looks like an import error, so you probably didn't reinstall all required packages / modules in the new virtualenv.

Comment: That's all the info I get. Strangely, when installing Virtualenv the first time it errors with a stack trace, but the second time it works. There was no problem activating the env or installing Django. The function it's hanging on is part of Flup but I installed Flup to the env and it made no difference.

Comment: when _creating_ the Virtualenv the first time it errors